# Relative clauses: connecting sentences

Tags: relative-pronouns, relative-clauses

Can you give some help, please? According to the exercise, I have to combine the two sentences with a relative pronoun.

1. A car didn't stop at the crossoroads. It was going fast.
   A car, which was going fast, didn't stop at the crossoroads.
2. The girls laughed during the film. They were sitting behind me.
   The girls who were sitting behind me laughed during the film.
3. The boy plays tennis very well. His brother is a tennis instructor.
   The boy whose brother is a tennis player plays tennis very well.

Do you agree? There is no context given and sometimes it is hard to distinguish defining from non-defining relative clauses! Maybe both options are acceptable. Thanks a lot beforehand!

Comment: Yours reads like a better Question than the exercise’s.
*A car, which was going fast, didn't stop at the crossroads* might be grammatically acceptable - and there isn’t a significantly better way of combining those sentences - but you are never going to hear that outside a classroom.
The same is true of the other examples; prolly more so.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you add commas to set the adjectival phrases apart from the rest of the sentence, but otherwise all are correct.  For example:

> "He, who asked a question on ELL, got the answer he was looking for."

It's acceptable to use either two separate sentences or a relative clause, but the relative clause sounds more "fluent".  In general, it's better to combine two short sentences into one sentence, if you can do it in a grammatically correct way.